# Monitoring system with windows update support

Tags: monitoring, windows-update

A client has requested a monitoring system that allows to send updates to computers. Time ago I heard of MARS console, but I'm not even able to find a web. It was supposed to be able to update all software in the computer.

Do you know of a monitoring system that allows this?

EDIT: With monitoring I refer to CPU, disk space, cpu load... WSUS is not suitable for that, as far as I know.

We want to deploy one system instead of two, if it's posible.

Comment: What's wrong with WSUS?

Comment: WSUS, SCCM, SCOM.  Really, you should learn to do your own research/Google queries.

Comment: As far as I know, WSUS does not do monitoring, does it? Maybe the question is not clear, I'll update it.

Comment: Monitoring performance metrics and Windows updates have nothing to do with each other.

Comment: I know they have nothing to do. I'm just asking if there is a solution that can manage both things, as I was told they exist. Thanks for your explanations about Google and WSUS, but I know both of them.

Comment: I have a script that can do both things, and also change the desktop background!  If you'd like, I can call it an enterprise monitoring, updating and personalization suite and sell it to you for a mere $15,000/yr.  ... Or, you could pause for a minute to consider what these multiple-systems-in-one really are behind the scenes and give a little more thought to your overall system architecture/design goals here.

Comment: If you could integrate that script in let's say, Nagios, I would pay for it, considering you manage to show available updates for each computer and chose which to install, all in the Nagios console.

Comment: @MikeB  You're describing WSUS.  Set up WSUS and integrate it into your existing monitoring system.  Easy, quick and free.

Comment: @HopelessN00b That could be an interesting way, but I doubt my boss would want to develop that if there's something that already does it. In fact our first proposal was to offer WSUS and Nagios but customer demanded for an all-in-one console. Development time wouldn't be accepted nor by boss nor by the customer.

Comment: It's called a plugin, [and for example, here are some scripts to integrate WSUS updates in Nagios](http://networklore.com/nagios-plugin-for-windows-security-updates/), care of Google.  An all-in-one Nagios console that would take all of a few minutes of "development time."

Comment: It's interesting, but as I said, development isn't the first option so I didn't googled for what I don't need. The plugin you linked only shows warnings (and the one in frank4dd.com seems to be down), so applying them would take more than minutes. Anyway, I really appreciate your efforts -as a former programmer, I woulnd't like anything more than developing that console for Nagios- but it's not the target of my question. So please, don't insist in anything else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Windows Updates, you can setup up [WSUS](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsserver/bb332157.aspx). This will give you the ability to deploy Windows updates to Windows machines on the domain. Unless you're looking to do more than Windows updates and deploy/update other software, there's applications such as [Dell KACE](http://www.kace.com/solutions/business-needs/systems-deployment).

Answer (score 0):

The answer (at least one answer) came from the advertisements in this page:
[LogMeIn Central](https://secure.logmein.com/products/central/learnmore/Updates.aspx)

The LogMeIn Central Updates product allows setting alerts and includes Windows Update management capabilities in one console.

Comment: what? I...just...what? I'd flag this as spam but LogMeIn do not strike me as a company who would spam websites with ads...